# How does AutoMapper store all its maps in memory?

Tags: automapper, automapper-3

I wanted to know how AutoMapper stores all its MappingConfigurations in memory. Also how can I remove all the mappings from memory without using Mapper.Reset.
I am using AutoMapper 3.2.1